# Does fetching gps location in high accuracy mode deducts money from our balance?

Tags: android, gps

Hi I am working on a project which requires fetching of user's current coordinates and I am fetching it in high accuracy mode.

Ever since I started testing out this application in my device I have noticed that my money is getting deducted from my balance I am not sure why is it happening.

I currently dont have a data pack and my mobile data is turned of in my device but I am connected to wifi. Even if some application is using internet for some purpose it should make use of the my wifi connection right?

Can anyone please explain me why is my balance getting deducted (if you have faced similar issue) ? Is it really because of the fetching of location in high accuracy mode ?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I get this dialog box frequently:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPS coordinates on a android device (or any device for that matter) is received in 2 ways.

1. From a GPS hardware that connects to your GPS Satellites
2. From your network, via the GPS location of the tower to which your SIM card is connected to.

The GPS hardware connects to multiple satellites and approximates your location to a point. And this location is the most accurate you can get. It consumes a lot more battery and decipates a lot more heat on the devices, since a lot of current is needed to read from the GPS satellites. This does not use the network at all. If your SIM card cannot make phone calls/and/or/data even then this location can be received.

Your network GPS also does similar, but it takes GPS coordinates of the towers closeby (to which the SIM card is connected to, and then approximates the location of your device. This GPS location (in comparison with the GPS hardware) calculates a less accurate. This consumes GPRS/3G data bandwidth and you will be charged for this.

Both the hardware are completely independent.

Now, some smart ass developers in Google have used sensors like compass, rotation, movement to develop something called AGPS, which takes the GPS location from the GPS hardware, and then uses network and sensor information to ensure that your location is known without use of too much power, and there by lesser heat decipation. This is called AGPS.

Comment: Thank you for the ans. So its for sure that my balance is getting detected because of fetching GPS location! Is there any way to avoid this? Does having a data pack avoid this (I currently dont have a data pack). I dont want the user to uninstall my application since its detecting the balance.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid making use of AGPS ?

Comment: If you know the solution for this then can you please answer this question of my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225942/avoid-making-use-of-agps-or-network-gps-to-avoid-detection-of-money-android