# Avoid making use of AGPS or network GPS to avoid deduction of money Android

Tags: android, gps

Following up with the ans I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225535/does-fetching-gps-location-in-high-accuracy-mode-detects-money-from-our-balance/25225775#25225775) I would like to know how can I avoid making use of AGPS or network GPS.

I am using `LocationClient` in my code to fetch user's current location. The `LocationClient` is a fused API which automatically makes use of `GPS_PROVIDER` or `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

My main intention here is to avoid deduction of money (For more information on this refer the SO question that I have linked above).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use fused.  Use GPS_PROVIDER alone.  That will use just your GPS hardware.  The entire point of fused is to use AGPS and network to reduce the need for GPS and reduce battery use.

Comment: Is there no other way to avoid deduction of money ? cause there are few devices which does have GPS like this one here http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-star-s5282/p/itmdv6f7vxnkfwqs The fused API helps me a lot without making me worry about devices like these.

Comment: If you don't have GPS hardware, then you can use network or fused, but these WILL use the network, so it will cost you money if you pay per megabyte.  There's no way to have your cake and eat it too here-  you can avoid all network use, or you can use the network.  You could, however, code it to use GPS on devices with it and FUSED or NETWORK_PROVIDER when there isn't.

Comment: I guess I dont have any other way. Just curious though does all the app which fetch user's current location make use of this method ? i.e using fused api only when gps is not present ???

Comment: I would say most don't use FUSED at all.  Its a newer API and isn't available on all phones (it requires a google licensed OEM or a pirated copy of Google Play Services).  Also most people don't care about the cost of the network IO, as most people in the US and EU are on unlimited data plans.  So I'd say no-  most people just code for GPS provider if they need accuracy or NETWORK provvider if they want to save battery, with a few newer app using FUSED and not caring if there's phones where it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

LocationClient is the new GPS solution on Android which uses network/GPS and sensors to give you optimal location. When I say optimal I mean, battery, heat, cost and accuracy. Infact it is atleast 80% better when considering all costs.

I would strongly recommend that you use LocationClient API's. If you dont, you are better off using just GPS Provider from your LocationManager. LocationClient is a overkill.

Comment: Depends on your requirements whether its better considering all costs.  If you need to optimize for one of those parameters, FUSED doesn't win-  for example if you need extreme accuracy.  Or if you don't need accuracy at all so want to save battery.  Also to nitpick-  the only tradeoff is accuracy vs battery use.  Heat and battery are the same-  using battery causes heat as a waste product.